# paginate_links returns nothing

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

My
`paginate_links`
are always returning nothing for my custom post types. I've adjusted the 'Reading' settings in Wordpress to 4 posts and I've also tried resetting the permalinks but nothing seems to help.

The code for my loop:

```
    <section class="showcase__articles">
      <div class="page-width">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <div class="articles__cards for-sale__article mobile__one-col">
            
        <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
        $loop = new WP_Query( 
            array(  'post_type' => 'Paarden',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'ras',
                            'field'    => 'name',
                            'terms'    => 'fries',
                        ),
                    ),
                )); 
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 
          <div class="articles__card">
            <?php $sold = get_field('status'); if( $sold == 'verkocht' ) { ?><p class="articles__card-badge"><?php pll_e( "Sold" ); ?></p><?php } else {}; ?>
            <div class="articles__card-image">
                <?php 
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                $alt_text = get_post_meta($image_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="articles__card-content">
              <h2 class="articles__card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <p class="articles__card-desc"><?php the_field('subtitle'); ?></p>
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              <a class="btn articles__card-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php pll_e( "Read more" ); ?></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="pagination">
            <?php echo paginate_links(array('total' => $loop->max_num_pages)); ?>
        </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
     
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Screenshot of the empty pagination container:
[Empty pagination container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvuXG.png)

I just want a functional pagination with a next, previous and number of pages buttons.

I've found some posts online from people that are running into the same issue, although their solutions don't work for me. I've tried multiple variants, but I've never gotten to the point where it returned anything.